# 2003 crown Vic problems with burning smell

Tags: brakes, caliper

When I drive the car for a period of time the driver side front tire area releases a burning smell and occasionally white smoke will billow up from there. Now the car was owned by my great grandma brand new from the lot but sat for a long time when she got ill i recently just got
Given the vehicle any idea what it is

Comment: How many miles does the car have? Have you had to periodically add oil? My first guess would be that the car has a slow oil leak somewhere. When the engine warms up, the oil flows onto a very hot part of the engine, and begins to "burn". Try opening the hood and see if you can find where the smoke is coming from.